# Vimeo New API - authentication and search private videos

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

My task is to

1. Search private video of a user. Later link of selected video is pasted to an editor of admin and user may look at the video when they open the page.
2. Search and get embed code for the video, paste that in editor. Later end user will open that page and see the video.

Make sure if user copy paste the video link in another page outside our platform. They should not view the video.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer [token]');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('consumer_key', '[token]');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('consumer_secret', '[token]');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.0');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('client_id', '[token]');
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);        
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(ajaxOptions);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
```

I am not sure what is step by step procedure to do the above task.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your above code.

1. You should **NEVER** publicly display your consumer secret. Any time Vimeo finds a consumer secret released to the public they will immediately disable your app, and you will need to make a new one. I did not have to perform that action this time because...
2. The consumer key you have provided is not a valid consumer key. I can not find it in Vimeo's database. If this key is valid, contact Vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact so they can try to help you secure your app.
3. API 3 never allows consumer_key, consumer_secret or client_id headers. All authorization goes through the "Authorization" header, which you can read about at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication
4. The /oauth/access_token endpoint is only used in the [authentication worfkow](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication). If you want to make api requests they happen right off of api.vimeo.com. You can read more about making api requests here : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec
5. To make a search request you make an api call to api.vimeo.com/videos?query=[YOUR SEARCH QUERY]. But this wont work as you intend because...
6. Vimeo search does not contain private videos. This is consistent with Vimeo's on site functionality. It may eventually support private videos but there is no time frame on that. If you want to search private videos I recommend you index all private videos in a separate search service such as solr, elasticsearch, or a third party api based service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Token and keys which I wrote in my question is not the original. I did use the proper token and key in my code though. I later found out private videos search is not supported by vimeo.

Comment: Glad you were on top of it. I hoped that was the case but needed to be careful.